# Steam Community Group

Tags: discussion

[Gaming Stack Exchange Steam Community Group](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/stackexchange)

Enables us to communicate even while playing, and play games together.

(Jeff will be made Owner if he joins, and ♦ on the site should be Officers)

Comment: This is a nice idea

Comment: You should update the group's icon to the new heart decal.

Comment: done. (had to use the background, as steam doesn't like tranparency.)

Answer (score 1):

You can find me as Jimmothy888

Answer (score 0):

You can find me as elpezmuerto

Answer (score 0):

I'm [STNO | Winter Phoenix](http://steamcommunity.com/id/WinterPhoenix)

Answer (score 0):

[[IAM] Marco Ceppi](http://steamcommunity.com/id/MarcoCeppi)

Answer (score 0):

My Steam ID is [CyberSkull](http://steamcommunity.com/id/CyberSkull), same as what I use here at SE.